# This just gave me this error "Deprecated: explode(): Passing null to parameter". Can anyone help me write it correctly?

Tags: php, deprecated, explode

```
$reward=explode('<a target="_blank" href="https://faucetpay.io/page/user-admin">DKAs1GrwvGx2jrFTtUDQJ2j5KbiWVhi2Jf </a>.</div>',explode('<div class="alert alert-success">',$faucet)[1])[0];

echo " ".$reward."   \n";
```

Comment: Is `$faucet` supposed to be the delimiter? The delimiter is supposed to be the first argument. And it can't be an empty string. If `$faucet` can be empty, you need to check for this and set it to a proper default value, or skip the call.

Comment: Have you read https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php - the separator should be the first argument.

Comment: do you mind rewriting it for me I'm a beginner so I'm finding a hard time understanding some things